# CSS font embedding with own CDN not working

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

I am having a problem with font embedding with CSS. I only have very few experiences with front end. Now I am about to deploy my website. But before I deploy it, first I uploaded all asset files like js,css and fonts to my CDN server. But my website is still on localhost. Then I changed all the asset link to my cdn link and I accessed my website on localhost. All javascript files on CDN are working perfectly with my local website. CSS files are also working fine except font embedding.

> I am embedding font like this before I change links to CDN.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TharLon';
    src: url(../fonts/tharlon.woff) format('woff');
}

.font-class{
    font-family:'TharLon' !important;
}
```

It is working perfectly when all are on localhost.

> Then I changed all links to CDN and embedded font like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TharLon';
    src: url('http://d3ewfjbf99d22n.cloudfront.net/assets/fonts/tharlon.woff') format('woff');
}

.font-class{
    font-family:'TharLon' !important;
}
```

When I do this, font embedding is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

As you seem to be using an Amazon S3, you can add the required headers as follows:

- Login to your Amazon account.
- Choose your S3 Bucket
- Click on Edit CORS Configuration
- Add following code and save all settings

  ```
  <CORSConfiguration>
      <CORSRule>
          <AllowedOrigin>http://www.example1.com</AllowedOrigin>

          <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>

          <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
      </CORSRule>
  </CORSConfiguration>
  ```

From: https://www.maxcdn.com/one/tutorial/how-to-use-cdn-with-webfonts/ (scroll down to S3 bucket)

Comment: Thank u . I am using S3 . I hope this will work . I will try on this .

Comment: It worked.  I had to wait fortge server cache finished.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear your have a problem with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

I just added this to a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L4kvz59z/) and I got this `error`:

> Font from origin 'https://d3ewfjbf99d22n.cloudfront.net' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: So . Do I have to configure my server to enable it ?

Comment: I will add this to apache config file.

Comment: # Apache config
<FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>

Comment: @Waiyan I'm not sure, I'm not an Apache user.

Comment: Whether your post is very helpful to me. I am still trying on it.

Comment: @Wai Yan Hein I cannot complete the cdn operation between my two servers with just this header set. : <FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff)"> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" </FilesMatch>. how can you did this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that your CDN accepts the OPTIONS method used by some browsers before get an endpoint.

In CloudFront (AWS) only GET and HEAD methods are accepted by default